# CocoaAsyncSocket / GCDAsyncSocket: close SSL/TLS session (back to unencrypted TCP connection) / establish second SSL session / renegotiate session

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, gcdasyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket

I have a problem connecting to a server over SSL. As soon as I execute a special command, the service on the server I'm talking to switches and looses the SSL session, forcing me to make a new SSL handshake.
How can I do so with GCDAsyncSocket? After I call `[socket startTLS:...]` there is no possibility to close the SSL session (something like `[socket stopTLS]`) and reopen it again or to renegotiate the SSL session. I also cannot disconnect and reconnect the TCP socket or connect using a second socket because then I will start again at the entry point service I get when first connecting to the server.

I am grateful for any idea you can provide me!

Thanks in advance.

--edit--

Still couldn't figure out how to establish a second SSL session without having to open a new TCP socket. I also couldn't find any way to renegotiate a SSL session manually...

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance!